# Having problems parsing numerical command-line arguments

Tags: python

I am making a super simple program that strips even or odd numbers from a string given on the command line. For example:

```
$ test.py 1 1234
13
$ test.py 2 1234
24
```

The problem is I can't get it to work. It prints the usage instead of the expected numbers.

```
$ test.py 1 1234  
Usage: test.py [option] [number], etc..
```

Also, this should print out the usage, but instead does nothing:

```
$ python2.7 test.py 1  
$
```

Why doesn't the program output the usage? `len(sys.argv)` is `< 2` so it should print usage, correct?

```
def oddtarray(num):
    tlist = map(int, str(num))
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) != 0]
    return tnum
def eventarray(num):
    tlist = map(int, str(num))
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) == 0]
    return tnum
def transform():
    try:
        odd = int(''.join(map(str, eventarray(sys.argv[2]))))
        even = int(''.join(map(str, oddtarray(sys.argv[2]))))
            if len(sys.argv) == 3:
                if sys.argv[1] == 1:
                    print odd
                elif sys.argv[1] == 2:
                    print even
                else:
                    usage()
            else:
                usage()
    except IndexError:
        if len(sys.argv) < 2:
            usage()
def usage():
    print 'Usage: test.py [option] [number]'
    print 'Options: \n[1] - Remove even numbers\n[2] - Remove odd numbers'

transform()
```

Comment: Try just "python" without the 2.7?

Comment: `transform` has an indentation error. Is the `else` clause that runs `usage` unconditionally paired with the `try` instead of the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes You are correct. Sorry first time posting, lots of errors

Comment: @Joshua: don't do it. It destroys the link between the answer (which is anterior to your edit) and the question. It's better to just comment on the answer in that case.

Comment: Guys Joshua edited the title. It's not as funny as before but I think we could cut down the downvotes... Way to go, encouraging new users which actually _respond_ to the comments.

Comment: Okay I'll have that in mind the next time I post a question :)

Comment: @Joshua Excellent, thanks for being receptive to our feedback. You're a real rarity around here. Writing a good question is almost as difficult as writing good code. Ha!

Comment: @JohnKugelman if you think writing a good question is difficult, try it on meta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the OP and one other answer so far, I don't see why you would compute both the odd and even lists knowing you'll only need one of them -- it's short distance from "simple" to "simply inefficient".  How about we delay the "hard work" of thinning the lists until we've finished the "easy work" of decoding the arguments:

```
import sys

def oddtarray(digits):
    tlist = map(int, digits)
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) != 0]
    return int(''.join(map(str, tnum)))

def eventarray(digits):
    tlist = map(int, digits)
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) == 0]
    return int(''.join(map(str, tnum)))

def transform():
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:

        try:
            if sys.argv[1] == "1":
                print oddtarray(sys.argv[2])
            elif sys.argv[1] == "2":
                print eventarray(sys.argv[2])
            else:
                usage()
        except ValueError:
            usage()
    else:
        usage()

def usage():
    print 'Usage: test.py [option] [number]'
    print 'Options: \n[1] - Remove even numbers\n[2] - Remove odd numbers'

transform()
```

Specific issues with the original program: the `odd` and `even` variables are reversed; command line arguments are being treated as numbers instead of as strings that look like numbers; the validity of the length of the command line argument list is being tested **after** items have already been extracted from it -- it should be tested before; the possibility of an IndexError exception is more likely due to programmer error than user error -- a ValueError exception is more likely due to user error (entering non-digits).

Comment: That's a nice addendum to @JeanFrancoisFabre's answer, but it doesn't answer the question itself. I recommend addressing the problem(s) in the question directly so your answer stands alone.

Comment: This answer is excellent! Every problem is fixed and it is much more efficient. Thank you, sir. For some reason this piece of code is actually fixing the output problems, although I don't actually know why

Comment: good remark. So many mistakes we overlooked that part, even if that doesn't really answer the question. You could also propose to make a generic odd/event routine just changing the == by !=, drop the `list(digits)` because `digits` is already an interable  ... the list of potential improvements here is big. Would be good for code review now :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman, I've added a laundry list of issues with the original code at the end of my answer -- thank you.  Let me know if you think it needs a more descriptive approach.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I've dropped the `list()` calls.  It usually takes me a while to clean up all the little stuff.

Comment: The OP accepted your answer: it means that it suits him best so you just deserve it :)

Answer (score 4):

`sys.argv[1] == 1` is not possible. You mean: `sys.argv[1] == "1"`. Those are strings, not numbers.

Your argument parsing would require some cleaning. No need for all those checks and exceptions to do such a simple task.

Allow me to "code review" & fix your code (I focused on the arg parsing part, protecting the integer parsing by a try/except `ValueError` printing usage and testing the number of arguments):

```
import sys
def oddtarray(num):
    tlist = map(int, str(num))
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) != 0]
    return tnum
def eventarray(num):
    tlist = map(int, str(num))
    tnum = [x for x in tlist if (x % 2) == 0]
    return tnum

def transform():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        # not enough arguments: print usage and that's it!
        usage()
    else:
        try:
          command = int(sys.argv[1])  # convert to integer
          odd = int(''.join(map(str, eventarray(sys.argv[2]))))
          even = int(''.join(map(str, oddtarray(sys.argv[2]))))

          if command == 1:
              print(odd)
          elif command == 2:
              print(even)
          else:
              usage()
        except ValueError as e:
           # some string to integer went wrong: display detailed exception
           # just in case, then usage
           print(str(e))
           usage()
def usage():
    print('Usage: test.py [option] [number]')
    print('Options: \n[1] - Remove even numbers\n[2] - Remove odd numbers')

transform()
```

now it's really "super simple", and as a bonus, it works :)